# Error in SvelteKit component package type declarations

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component

I have made a component and have packaged and published it to the npm.
the code can be viewed at [Github](https://github.com/Sourabhpatel1/svelte-combobox.git).

when I install and import the component package to my route in +page.svelte file I get the following error `Cannot find module 'svelte-combobox/ComboBox.svelte' or its corresponding type declarations.`

the code in +page.svelte file is as follows :

```
<script lang="ts">
    import ComboBox  from 'svelte-combobox/ComboBox.svelte';
    let options = [
        { id: 1, name: "Option 1", value: "1" },
        { id: 2, name: "Option 2", value: "2" },
        { id: 3, name: "Option 3", value: "3" },
        { id: 4, name: "Option 4", value: "4" },
        { id: 5, name: "Option 5", value: "5" },
        { id: 6, name: "Option 6", value: "6" },
        { id: 7, name: "Option 7", value: "7" },
        { id: 8, name: "Option 8", value: "8" },
        { id: 9, name: "Option 9", value: "9" },
        { id: 10, name: "Option 10", value: "10" }
    ] 
</script>

<ComboBox options={options} id="1" on:select={(e)=>{console.log(e.detail)}}/>
```

I followed the packaging guidelines from the official [documentation](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/packaging) for packaging sveltekit component libraries.

I think the problem lies in the package.json in

```
{
"exports": {"./ComboBox.svelte": {
            "types : "./dist/ComboBox.svelte.d.ts",
            "svelte" : "./dist/ComboBox.svelte"
        }
    }
}
```

But I can not figure out why am I getting the error message as the imported component seems to be working fine and the project builds without any errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you read the [section on TypeScript](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/packaging#typescript)?

To make types work you probably will have to define `typesVersions` as shown there or change module resolution to `bundler`. Currently you did neither.

Comment: Using "moduleResolution" : "Bundler" solves the problem but using typesVersions method does not. I guess I'll edit the readme.md file in the package.